# Way to differentiate between a background notifcation tap to a in-app received notification?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is there a way to tell the difference between a push notification that a user taps WITH the app in background and a notification that a user received while in app? I am not talking about when the app is closed. That I can already handle. I'm specifically talking about when the app is still open, but is in background. ig) user is in another app but didn't close the app you're in. Both (background app and in-app notifications) seem to both go through the `ReceivedRemoteNotification` callback. Which works fine. I just want to know if the user was in app so I know whether or not to show an alert. If the user has the app in background, they already get a push notification, therefore does not warrant an in-app alert. Where as when user is in app, we would want an in-app alert because they won't get the push notification. Although probably not relevant, here's my `ReceivedRemoteNotification` method.

```
    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication app, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        // Process a notification received while the app was already open
        ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check application state before displaying notification.
If app status is Active, your app is in foreground.

```
if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
{
          ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);
}
```

Comment: Ended up doing something like this. I'll check it though because it might help others.